# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel binding with a Hierarchy of Collections

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, binding

I have the following Model design.

Template contains a list of Categories.
Categories contains a List of Items.

Thus there is 3 layer hierarchy. Because the UI design requires that all 3 levels be created on 1 page, I have had to write some of my own code to get this working. It looks as follows:

[image: Page Design]

I can get it to submit back to the Create Action Method and the FormCollection looks as follows.

[image: FormValues for Create]

The problem I am having is that the UpdateModel works for the Template and Category level but the Items are not populated for the Categories. The Html looks as follows. As you can see, I have used the Category[guid_value].Items[guid_value] syntax for id. Shouldn't it figure out the binding automagically based on that?

[image]

**Is there something I am missing or have to do in order to get the binding to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want your html to bind correctly to your model you have to pay some attention to html you render. The problem that i can see with your html is

```
<input type='hidden' value = 'Items.Index' value= 'some_guid' autocomplete = 'off'/>
```

with this html model binder will try to bind Items as children of Template object where it will not find any property named Items and these values will not be bound to the model. you have to change your hidden field to

```
<input type='hidden' name = 'Categories[category's guid].Items.Index' value = 'some guid' autocomplete = 'off'/>
```

and you have to just call updatemodel in your action method like

```
UpdateModel(yourobject);
```

i have not tested this code but i am more than certain that changing your html this way will get you sorted.
@Mlchael Grassman you don't have to use integer based id's to bind collection anymore. plz read [steve's post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for more information. Actually you don't need GUID either but a random number that is unique in page's context provided that you put an extra hidden field with name index and value set to above mentioned random number. I have blogged about Master detail form in asp.net mvc using (and modifying) BeginCollectionItem method written by Steve. in part [one](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-i.html) of this blog series i simply showed how you can dynamically add fields of your detail record on client side without ajax call. In [second](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-ii.html) part i brought the editor template of detail record to jquery templating engine and rendering it on client side as it would appear if rendered through ajax call.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!! Thank you Muhammad. One of the frustrating things is the Conventions used for MVC that are not so publicized. How did you figure all this out? :-)

Comment: Categories is property of your object but items is not. its rather property of an element of Categories so you have to put it Categories[guid].Items.index where guid roughly relates to id of category in Categories collection

Answer (score 1):

By default MVC uses the following convention for naming.

```
Category[0].Items[0]
Category[0].Items[1]
Category[1].Items[0]
Category[1].Items[1]
```

You can include your own Update by using the following TryUpdateModel.  This woud probably need some sort of loop but should get you started.

```
TryUpdateModel(Category[Guid].Items[Guid], "Category[Guid].Items[Guid]", null, new string[] { "ExcludedPropery1", "ExcludedPropery2", "ExcludedProperyN", });
```

Comment: How would I do that. Write a loop to go get the GUID from the FormValues? The guid is created for me by the same approach here. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: I was just point out the default behavior that MVC using in it TryUpdateModel.  If you wanted to stick with the quids you have to provide which objects should be mapped to which form collection.  Basically your looping through the form collection and doing what mvc does with it's int based indexes.  I don't believe MVC will do this for you.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Michael. Is there a way to write a custom binding method that will allow me to override the use of ints with guids? Because technically Category[0] and Category[GUID_VALUE] should not really be that different. Or maybe better yet, is there a more standard way to achieve this design without using GUIDs.

Comment: The standard way would be to use int based indexes and have your guid values be a hidden field so they come back with the form data.  So you could reference them with Category[0].Item[0].GuidColumn